# ¿Por qué no puedo instalar OpenGl en Debian?

Tags: debian

Estoy intentando instalar Mesa 11.1.2, solucioné todos los problemas de dependencias pero al ejecutar `make` tengo las siguiente salida:

```
Making all in src
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src'
Making all in .
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src'
Making all in gtest
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/gtest'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/gtest'
Making all in util
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/util'
make  all-recursive
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/util'
Making all in .
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/util'
make[4]: Nothing to be done for 'all-am'.
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/util'
Making all in tests/hash_table
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/util/tests/hash_table'
make[4]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/util/tests/hash_table'
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/util'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/util'
Making all in mapi/glapi/gen
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/mapi/glapi/gen'
make  all-am
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/mapi/glapi/gen'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/mapi/glapi/gen'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/mapi/glapi/gen'
Making all in mapi
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/mapi'
make  all-recursive
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/mapi'
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/mapi'
make[4]: Nothing to be done for 'all-am'.
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/mapi'
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/mapi'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/mapi'
Making all in glsl
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/glsl'
make  all-am
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/glsl'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/glsl'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/glsl'
Making all in mesa
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/mesa'
updating main/git_sha1.h
make  all-recursive
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/mesa'
Making all in .
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/mesa'
updating main/git_sha1.h
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/mesa'
Making all in main/tests
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/mesa/main/tests'
make[4]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/mesa/main/tests'
Making all in drivers/dri
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/mesa/drivers/dri'
Making all in common
make[5]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/mesa/drivers/dri/common'
Making all in xmlpool
make[6]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/mesa/drivers/dri/common/xmlpool'
make  all-am
make[7]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/mesa/drivers/dri/common/xmlpool'
make[7]: Nothing to be done for 'all-am'.
make[7]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/mesa/drivers/dri/common/xmlpool'
make[6]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/mesa/drivers/dri/common/xmlpool'
make[6]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/mesa/drivers/dri/common'
make[6]: Nothing to be done for 'all-am'.
make[6]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/mesa/drivers/dri/common'
make[5]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/mesa/drivers/dri/common'
Making all in i915
make[5]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/mesa/drivers/dri/i915'
make[5]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[5]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/mesa/drivers/dri/i915'
Making all in i965
make[5]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/mesa/drivers/dri/i965'
make[5]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[5]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/mesa/drivers/dri/i965'
Making all in nouveau
make[5]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/mesa/drivers/dri/nouveau'
make[5]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[5]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/mesa/drivers/dri/nouveau'
Making all in r200
make[5]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/mesa/drivers/dri/r200'
make[5]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[5]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/mesa/drivers/dri/r200'
Making all in radeon
make[5]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/mesa/drivers/dri/radeon'
make[5]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[5]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/mesa/drivers/dri/radeon'
Making all in swrast
make[5]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/mesa/drivers/dri/swrast'
make[5]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[5]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/mesa/drivers/dri/swrast'
make[5]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/mesa/drivers/dri'
  GEN      all-local
  GEN      all-local
make[5]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/mesa/drivers/dri'
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/mesa/drivers/dri'
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/mesa'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/mesa'
Making all in loader
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/loader'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/loader'
Making all in glx
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/glx'
Making all in .
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/glx'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/glx'
Making all in tests
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/glx/tests'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/glx/tests'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/glx'
Making all in egl
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/egl'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/egl'
Making all in gallium
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/gallium'
Making all in auxiliary
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/gallium/auxiliary'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/gallium/auxiliary'
Making all in auxiliary/pipe-loader
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/gallium/auxiliary/pipe-loader'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/gallium/auxiliary/pipe-loader'
Making all in drivers/ddebug
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/gallium/drivers/ddebug'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/gallium/drivers/ddebug'
Making all in drivers/noop
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/gallium/drivers/noop'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/gallium/drivers/noop'
Making all in drivers/trace
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/gallium/drivers/trace'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/gallium/drivers/trace'
Making all in drivers/rbug
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/gallium/drivers/rbug'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/gallium/drivers/rbug'
Making all in drivers/svga
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/gallium/drivers/svga'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/gallium/drivers/svga'
Making all in winsys/svga/drm
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/gallium/winsys/svga/drm'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/gallium/winsys/svga/drm'
Making all in drivers/r300
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/gallium/drivers/r300'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/gallium/drivers/r300'
Making all in drivers/radeon
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/gallium/drivers/radeon'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/gallium/drivers/radeon'
Making all in drivers/r600
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/gallium/drivers/r600'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/gallium/drivers/r600'
Making all in winsys/radeon/drm
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/gallium/winsys/radeon/drm'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/gallium/winsys/radeon/drm'
Making all in drivers/softpipe
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/gallium/drivers/softpipe'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/gallium/drivers/softpipe'
Making all in drivers/llvmpipe
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/gallium/drivers/llvmpipe'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/gallium/drivers/llvmpipe'
Making all in winsys/sw/null
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/gallium/winsys/sw/null'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/gallium/winsys/sw/null'
Making all in winsys/sw/dri
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/gallium/winsys/sw/dri'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/gallium/winsys/sw/dri'
Making all in winsys/sw/kms-dri
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/gallium/winsys/sw/kms-dri'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/gallium/winsys/sw/kms-dri'
Making all in winsys/sw/wrapper
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/gallium/winsys/sw/wrapper'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/gallium/winsys/sw/wrapper'
Making all in state_trackers/dri
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/gallium/state_trackers/dri'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/gallium/state_trackers/dri'
Making all in targets/dri
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/gallium/targets/dri'
  GEN      all-local
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/gallium/targets/dri'
Making all in state_trackers/xvmc
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/gallium/state_trackers/xvmc'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/gallium/state_trackers/xvmc'
Making all in targets/xvmc
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/gallium/targets/xvmc'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/gallium/targets/xvmc'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/gallium'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/gallium'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src/gallium'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2/src'
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all-am'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ricardo/Descargas/mesa-11.1.2'
```

Comment: Hola Ricardo, sería conveniente que indiques los permisos con que ejecutas make, y también agregar el archivo Makefile. Saludos

Comment: Hola @Santi92 el comando make ejecute con permisos de root, el archivo make es https://www.dropbox.com/s/cty48nrodj9c4al/Makefile?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logre solucionar mi problema agregando los repositorios de jessie backports e instalando desde los repositorios con sudo apt-get install 'nombre libreria', en mi caso

```
sudo apt-get install libglapi-mesa:i386/jessie-backports
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri:i386/jessie-backports
```